# Delete Formula in Excel based on IF TRUE while keeping the result

Tags: excel, formula

Is there anyway that I can delete the formula while keeping the value if my IF function is true? My formula is as follows:

`=IF(A50='TABS RECONCILIATION'!C5,'TABS RECONCILIATION'!G12,"N/A")`

I tried creating another statement by surrounding the above formula in another IF and it seems to work but I found no way in deleting the formula while keeping the result.

`=IF(IF(A50='TABS RECONCILIATION'!C5,'TABS RECONCILIATION'!G12,"N/A"),0,1)`

In other words is it possible if the first formula is correct to delete it and keep the result?

Comment: either with vba or copy / paste special values value, but not in a formula...

Comment: Gonna experiment with VBA then and hopefully come up with a result. Thanks